# What is the meaning behind the anime title "The World God only Knows"?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

Keima is a Capturing God, we all know that. After finishing the manga, I'm still confused by the title.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Keima mentioned this phrase in the final arc

Answer (score 4):

I think it means "the world only god knows". "God only knows" is an old way of language. So, I infer that since the setting (plot device) of this anime is about "capturing girls" , it is sort of a world that only Keima (god of capturing) knows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the meaning behind this title is that keima(God) has to help girls escape from their dark states using love and I think it’s telling that the world god only knows is to spread love to each other

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because Keima is the god  his own world of dating simulator games  and it is stated that Keima is the god of conquests.

Answer (score -2):

God is referring to him and the world god only knows is referring to the digital world and how he perceives it, many people know the digital world but not everyone has his perception on it, or it could be referring to how he sees the world as a dating simulator game and how he sees getting a girl as a game and no one else has the same perception as him of the fact that it's a game you might think that's not a world but world actually means his perception on it let's make this simpler and say the world the god of dating Sims only knows cus he's not a god just a dating sim god they were implying that in the title for sure and world doesn't mean an actual world cus that wouldn't make sense the world only the god of dating Sims would know is him thinking of capturing girls as a game   but hey that's just a theory a anime theory, in all honesty I think the only thing they were implying with this title was the world only the god of dating Sims knows as in a viewpoint that only the god of dating Sims has yeah I'm pretty sure of this cus when you think of it like the world only the god of dating Sims knows they don't mean world in a literal sense so it must mean a viewpoint only the god of dating Sims has what that viewpoint is idk but this has to be what it means, edit: nvm it was the god of conquests not dating Sims so this must mean when they say the world god only knows they must mean the world god of conquests only knows so this must mean the world inside his head where he sees conquering woman as a dating sim in his head because The world the god of conquests only knows must be his viewpoint of conquering woman as a game or his world of only 3d woman as there was a point where he envisioned himself in one of his dating Sims I could easily be wrong though this answer took me a lot and I mean a lot of thinking and it felt like my brain was gonna stop working but I came to a conclusion even if it is wrong it gives you a plausible scenario where the name could mean these options which is better then knowing nothing about the name and what it could mean so a plausible conclusion is better then none at all

Comment: Sorry, I feel this answer is hard to read and understood. I tried to edit and improve it, but I'm not sure how because I couldn't understand it in the first place. If anyone thinks they can grasp the meaning and improve it, then feel free to [edit] it.